# Where does the absolute value come from, calculating $\int \frac {du} {u \sqrt{(u^2 - a^2)}}$?

Tags: calculus

I want to prove the following calculation.
$$ \int \frac {du} {u \sqrt{(u^2 - a^2)}} = \frac {1}{a} \sec^{-1} \frac {|u|}{a}  + C$$

I know that $(sec^{-1} u)' = \frac {1} {|u| \sqrt{(u^2 -1)}}$ and I know why the absolute value is in it.

However I don't know how to derive the absolute value term $\frac {|u|}{a} $ in the above integration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let  $$\displaystyle I = \int\frac{1}{u\sqrt{u^2-a^2}}du\;,$$ Now Let $u=a\sec \phi\;,$ Then $du = a\sec \phi \cdot \tan \phi d\phi$

So Integral $$\displaystyle I = \int\frac{a\sec \phi \cdot \tan \phi}{a^2\sec \phi \cdot \tan \phi}d\phi = \frac{1}{a}\int 1d\phi = \frac{1}{a}\phi +\mathcal{C} = \frac{1}{a}\sec^{-1}\left(\frac{u}{a}\right)+\mathcal{C}$$

If our Integral is $$\displaystyle \int\frac{1}{|u|\sqrt{u^2-a^2}}du\;,$$ Then we substute $|u| = a\sec \phi\;,$

and $du=\pm a \sec \phi \cdot \tan\phi d\phi$

So $$\displaystyle \displaystyle \int\frac{1}{|u|\sqrt{u^2-a^2}}du = \pm\frac{1}{a}\sec^{-1}\left(\frac{|u|}{a}\right)+\mathcal{C}$$

Answer (score 0):

You know that

$$(sec^{-1} u)' = \frac {1} {|u| \sqrt{(u^2 -1)}}$$

On both sides of the equation change  $ u \rightarrow u/a $ and simplify by  absorbing the constant $a$, and you are done. The reason for u not to exceed 1 is the same as the reason $u$ not to exceed $a$.

The same logical procedure applies for $ \int \dfrac{du}{\sqrt {u^2-1}}.$